# How do I remove a fill and leave only the outline in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I am new to any graphical editing software and I even do not know how can I formulate a question.

I have this:

[image: yellow letter M]

And I would like to only have the outline (removing the fill):

[image: Russian letter И]

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, by contour, do you mean outline?

Comment: Yes, I mean outline

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the stroke and fill for the object.

Select the object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Fill and Stroke window. On the Fill tab, change the fill to *No Paint* for transparent. On the Stroke paint tab, change the stroke to a solid color. If you want to change the thickness of the outline, go to the Stroke style tab, and change the width setting.

Comment: [![Hexagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Sil.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Sil.png) I cannot get the black to disappear and just leave the lines with the above answer

Comment: @user2436136 if you want to turn strokes into outlines, use *Path > Stroke to Path*. If you also want to combine the shapes then use *Path > Union*. Here's [an example showing the result](https://imgur.com/rub9mKc)