# Remove the fill (Colors) from image without removing outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have the following image which I want to remove only the fill which means colors,
[image]

I want to convert this into the only outline image with using whatever tool could possible. I have already referred [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67527/how-do-i-remove-a-fill-and-leave-only-the-outline-in-inkscape/67532#67532?newreg=823a1531728b4275b93ac1ec3c367897) Question but it doesn't work for me. Any kind of guidance will highly be appreciated.

Thankyou!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  You don't need to recreate anything. The Sri Lankan flag is available as a vector graphic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Sri_Lanka#/media/File:Flag_of_Sri_Lanka.svg - you can remove the fills in Illustrator

Comment: Please can you show me how to remove fill in illustrator?

Comment: There's nothing to show. You simply select the flag, and then set the fill to none, and stroke to black or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop:

- Convert  the image in a **Grayscale Mode**
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  Win to apply **Auto Levels**

[image: Lyon b/W]

- Go to menu **Filter** → **Other** → **High Pass**

[image: High Pass]

- Make **Auto Levels** again
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  Win to open the **Levels Window**
- Double click the black Eyedropper and make sure is 100% black. Double click the white Eyedropper and make sure is 100% white
- Use the **Black Eyedropper** to click a grey part of the image and the **White Eyedropper** to click the white. Repeat until getting the outline.

[image: eyedropper]

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>  Win to **Invert**
- Go to menu **Image** → **Adjustments** → **Threshold** to clean the image
- Use the **Eraser Tool** and the **Pencil Tool** to clean up the details

[image: End]

In this final image the job is partially done, except the lion's head and legs.

Answer (score 1):

I found this simple and easy to use tool online that does the job: https://vectordad.com/photo-to-outline/