# How can one remove the outline of a selection?

Tags: inkscape, svg, outline

I have a blue semicircle with a black outline, but I want the black outline to be removed.  I thought his would be easy, but have not been able to do it.

I thought by setting the stroke width to 0, it would solve the problem, but this appears to have no effect.

[image]

Comment: Choose nocolor on the bottom bar or the strole paint.

Comment: Setting the stroke width to zero should work, as well as removing the stroke altogether.

Comment: This is complementary to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67527/how-do-i-remove-a-fill-and-leave-only-the-outline-in-inkscape. Can someone please fix the typo in the title?

Comment: None of this works.  Inkscape appears not to differentiate from the outline and the interior.  Perhaps it has to do with the way this layer was constructed?

Comment: @bobbywang - yes the construction could certainly be the problem. The stroke and fill could be separate objects, or potentially there could be a black filled object under the blue object. Can you ungroup and move them apart?  You might also want to share the svg. Try using svgshare.com and post the link here.

Answer (score 5):

Use the **“Stroke paint”** tab (instead of your “Stroke style” one) and click on the leftmost button:

[image]

---

Or select your object, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click the cross on the leftmost position in the color palette:

[image]

---

Or right-click the stroke color and select “Remove stroke”.

[image]

Comment: None of this works.  Inkscape appears not to differentiate from the outline and the interior.  Perhaps it has to do with the way this layer was constructed?

Comment: @bobby, did you try to increase the with or color of your stroke to be sure that you have selected the correct object?